# Is there a way to make an ANT task run as Administrator in Windows Vista?

Tags: java, ant, windows-vista

As part of an installer, I need to run a batch file from ANT. If I run cmd.exe as Administrator and run the batch file, all is well since it has the appropriate administrative privileges. When the batch file is executed from ant, it fails, the same way it does if I were to run the batch file without administrative privileges. My question is, how can I run this batch file in Administrative mode from my ANT script?

```
<exec executable="cmd.exe" output="dir.txt" dir="c:/bin/">
<arg line="/c service.bat install"/>
</exec>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning off UAC seems to be the only option to allow this ant task to execute.

I tried making a shortcut to the batch file, and running that, since shortcuts can be set to 'run as administrator'. No luck there either as I get the prompt, but my batch file still fails out.

[http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/02/17/how-to-open-elevated-command-prompt-with-administrator-privileges-in-windows-vista/][1]

Answer (score 3):

At least XP has a `runas` command which you can try to use, something like:

```
runas /u:%COMPUTERNAME%\Administrator "cmd /c service.bat install"
```

When invoked, it will ask for password on console.

UPDATE: half of year later, I have upgraded to Windows 7. Here runas cannot be used for privilege elevation, but [Aaron Margosis](http://blogs.msdn.com/aaron_margosis/archive/2007/07/01/scripting-elevation-on-vista.aspx) has a solution:

```
// elevate.js -- runs target command line elevated
if (WScript.Arguments.Length >= 1) {
    Application = WScript.Arguments(0);
    Arguments = "";
    for (Index = 1; Index < WScript.Arguments.Length; Index += 1) {
        if (Index > 1) {
            Arguments += " ";
        }
        Arguments += WScript.Arguments(Index);
    }
    new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute(Application, Arguments, "", "runas");
} else {
    WScript.Echo("Usage:");
    WScript.Echo("elevate Application Arguments");
}
```

Which perhaps could be embedded in the installer if needed. For end users though, the [Script Elevation Power Toys](http://technet.microsoft.com/lt-lt/magazine/2007.06.utilityspotlight%28en-us%29.aspx) is more convienent, as suggested by another answer.

Comment: Oops, the question was about Vista. Well my answer is based on XP only, I am not sure if it applies to Vista.

Comment: Just tried that on Vista. Did not work... Thanks for the suggestion. Any more ideas anyone?

Comment: @Edward Try the Sysinternals command-line tool PsExec. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [Script Elevation PowerToy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.06.utilityspotlight.aspx).  It adds an elevate command that can be used to elevate privileges on the command line.

Comment: As part of an installer I can't guarantee that this power toy in installed on the machine, unfortunately. For anyone who wants to fix this problem on their machine to make life a little easier, that is a great suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, right.  I didn't consider that.  Actually, Windows tends to treat programs with certain names as always needing admin privileges (setup.exe for instance)... I wonder if that's true for setup.bat.

Answer (score 2):

I've stumbled upon a similar problem. The solution was to use [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) as the executable, and use it to call the batch file. PsExec is a powerful replacement for Windows' runas command.

Answer (score -2):

by using the elevate command prompt we can do this.

In Ant task we can use exec task to run any executable file.Like that we can also use command prompt with exec tas

```
<property name=”admincmd” value=”./elevate.cmd” />
<property name=”server.location” location=”c:/Apache/tomcat/bin” />

<exec executable=”${admincmd}” failonerror=”false”>
<arg value=”cmd” />
<arg value=”/k” />
<arg value=”${server.location}/service” />
<arg value=”install” />
</exec>
```

In the above code snippet elevate.cmd source can be downloaded from here

to run this code correctly we need to put the two files elevate.vbs, elevate.cmd in the same directory and  should be available in appropriate location which is define in the property admincmd.

[here](https://javatechguru.wordpress.com/2014/06/28/elevaterun-as-administrator-command-prompt-in-ant-task/) is the reference link of the original post